# Jupyter Notebook : How to select previous cell with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook

I try to select a previous cell in my notebook with Javascript only.
I managed to find the code to select the current and the next cell.

The script to select the next cell is :

```
Jupyter.notebook.select_next().get_selected_cell()
```

(it works)

So i tried with this to get the previous cell :

```
Jupyter.notebook.select_previous().get_selected_cell()
```

But it's not working,

does someone know the right code to do that ?

(Sorry if my english is a bit bad...)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
Jupyter.notebook.select_prev().get_selected_cell()
```

In Chrome the JavaScript Console has a autocomplete feature that helps exploring functions and properties of objects.

Comment: Thank you it works ! (I'm on firefox, but thanks for the advice, i'll try to use Chrome if i've other problem of this kind)